# Django error: settings.Databases improperly configured

Tags: django, sage

I'm completely new to Django and have no idea what that means. I'm really just trying to get codenode setup for sage. I've tried following the installation guide at codenode's website, but when I load localhost:8000, I get the following message and a whole bunch of debug text:

> settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.

Could someone walk me through this or at least point me to something? I've checked out a few of the other answers on the site, but I can't follow any of them. I'm really grateful for the help.

As requested, the DATABASES part of my settings file reads:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'           # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
DATABASE_NAME = os.path.join(HOME_PATH, 'codenode.db') # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
DATABASE_USER = ''             # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''         # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = ''             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = ''             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
```

Comment: You should also add your DATABASES part of your settings file for us to see why it is improperly configured.

Comment: Where's the settings file?

Comment: You may find http://groups.google.com/group/codenode-devel/browse_thread/thread/ded5ff248e3f7ec useful with respect to codenode and django issues.  I don't think codenode is actively developed now, though.

Answer (score 1):

A sample database setting for SQLite would look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': 'local.sqlite3',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this file located?

Comment: Search for `settings.py`. It is usually in a folder which has the same name with your project. Next to `urls.py`.

Comment: So it would be in the codenode.egg folder under python/dist-pacakges? I should mention I'm using Linux.

Comment: No. It should in your project folder. The folder that is created when you typed `django-admin.py startproject <projectname>`.

Comment: I think I found it, the file is the same except for "DATABASE_NAME = os.path.join(HOME_PATH, 'codenode.db')"

Comment: I tried changing the variable `DATABASE_NAME` to `'local.sqlite3'`, but when I executed `codenode-admin run` in the terminal it caused numerous errors and didn't run at all this time.